# Using dup2 when working with pipes fails despite having created valid file descriptors

Tags: c, shell, pipe

I'm making my own UNIX shell and I'm trying to implement support for (multiple) pipe commands. As you can see below, I'm creating the necessary file descriptors for each pipe and then creating a child process for each command using `fork()`. Inside the loop, I'm using `dup2` in order to copy the appropriate file descriptors inherited by the parent and redirect my input/output. However, when I test it using `echo tst | cw -w` , the `Failed to write output for the next command..` block is triggered. I don't understand what's causing this issue here. I've created the pipes with their file descriptors, I've added the appropriate checks for the first and last commands, I'm closing the inherited pipes before executing the command, etc.

Please help me pinpoint where my logic is faulty in the below code:

```
void execPipedCommands(char *input, char **commands)
{
    int numOfPipes = countCharOccurences(input, '|');
    int fds[2 * numOfPipes]; // two file descriptors per pipe needed for interprocess communication
    int i;

    // initialize all pipes and store their respective fds in the appropriate place in the array
    for (i = 0; i < 2 * numOfPipes; i++)
    {
        if (pipe(fds + 2 * i) == -1)
        {
            printf("Failed to create file descriptors for pipe commands!\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < numOfPipes+1; i++)
    {
        if (commands[i] == NULL)
            break;
        pid_t cpid;
        char *args[MAX_NUM_OF_COMMAND_WORDS] = {
            NULL,
        };
        parseCommandWords(commands[i], args);
        cpid = fork(); // start a child process
        if (cpid == -1)
        {
            printf("Failed to fork..\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if (cpid == 0)
        { // child process is executing
            if (i != 0)
            { // if this is not the first command in the chain
                // duplicate the file descriptor to read from the previous command's output
                if (dup2(fds[(i - 1) * 2], STDIN_FILENO) < 0)
                {
                    printf("Failed to read input from previous command..\n");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
            }

            // if this is not the last command in the chain
            if (i != numOfPipes+1 && commands[i + 1] != NULL)
            {
                // duplicate write file descriptor in order to output to the next command
                if (dup2(fds[(i * 2 + 1)], STDOUT_FILENO) < 0)
                {
                    printf("Failed to write output for the next command..\n");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
            }

            // close the pipes
            int j;
            for (j = 0; j < numOfPipes * 2; j++)
            { // close all copies of the file descriptors
                close(fds[j]);
            }

            // execute command
            if (execvp(commands[i], args) < 0)
            {
                printf("Failed to execute given command..");
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    // parent closes all original file descriptors
    for (i = 0; i < numOfPipes * 2; i++)
    {
        close(fds[i]);
    }

    // parent waits for all child processes to finish
    for (i = 0; i < numOfPipes + 1; i++)
        wait(0);
}
```

The `input` argument is simply the line that is read from the command line and the `commands` argument contains all the commands in the line read. So for the example I gave earlier, it would contain:

```
commands[0] = echo tst
commands[1] = cw -w
```

Comment: two bugs (not sure whether they cause the problem): a) the loop to create the pipe should only go up to `i < numOfPipes`. The way it is causes a buffer overflow b) `if (i != numOfPipes+1 && commands[i + 1] != NULL)` should be `if(i != numOfPipes && ...)` as your loop goes up to `i <= numOfPipes - 1`

Comment: Also, please make a habit of validating the function arguments at the beginning of the function. For example, `if (input == NULL || commands == NULL) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);` something like that

Comment: @kiner_shah You're right, I should have mentioned that they are already validated if this function is called :)

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt Thank you, I completely missed those.

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt Those seemed to be the issues. Once I corrected those, everything worked out!